# Graph $7y^2 - 4xy + 4x^2 = 24$

Tags: linear-algebra

Graph the equation of an ellipse $7y^2 - 4xy + 4x^2 = 24$.  Show your process and write a description of the graph and its key features. 
How do you write this in matrix form? I already solved the problem and found the ellipse.

Comment: Nope. What have you tried?

Comment: Use Desmos or Photomath.

Comment: I did the problem but im just worried that i did it wrong as i didn't use a matrix. I did it by completing the squares and solving for the equations.

Comment: If the requested output is a graph, it doesn't matter how you got the points.  I might have just made a spreadsheet that picked a lot of $x$ values and solved the quadratic for $y$.  What key points did you describe?

Comment: sorry im new to this site, i was wondering how to rewrite this in matrix form.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Here is a brute force approach. You have
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x & y \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} x & y \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} ax + by \\ cx + dy \end{pmatrix}
$$
Can you finish multiplication, apply the extra term and see what values $a,b,c,d$ have to take for your system to fit?

Comment: ooh okay thank you.